# React Native: Delete Image from firebase with "refFromURL"

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I try to delete a image from firebase. I think that the problem is that I ain't get the URL. After refresh the the flatlist I get following warning:

*"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Object {}"*

This warning only displays when I refresh the flatlist after deleting a Item.

The "downloadURL" is the URL who I download when I upload the image to firebase. Is it that URL who I should try to get or I'am wrong?

```js
export function deleteBoards(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('coachboards')
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection('userCoachboards')
        .doc(item.id)
        .delete()
        .then((snapshot) => {

          //Here I try to delete the image from firebase storage
          storage()
           .refFromURL(snapshot.data().downloadURL.url)
           .delete()
            .then(function () {
              resolve();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {console.log(error)});
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject();
        });
    });
  };
}
```

---

Updated result ✅

```
export function deleteBoards(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('coachboards')
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection('userCoachboards')
        .doc(item.id)
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
          //Here I try to delete the image from firebase storage
          storage()
            .refFromURL(item.downloadURL)
            .delete()
            .then(() => {
              resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject();
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject();
        });
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error text says you are not handling the error case if the `delete` fails. Try to add there an `reject()`:

```js
export function deleteBoards(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('coachboards')
        .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection('userCoachboards')
        .doc(item.id)
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
          //Here I try to delete the image from firebase storage
          firebase.storage()
           .refFromURL(item.downloadURL)
           .delete()
            .then( () => {
              resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject()
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject();
        });
    });
  };
}
```

Can you also log this `snapshot.data().downloadURL.url` value to see if it is correct.

Also shouldn't it be `firebase.storage()` instead of just `storage()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Mm, of course, my bad! but it still gives me the same error/warning. if I console log `console.log(item.downloadURL);` at the top it gives me the correct URL, but if I try this code `.refFromURL(snapshot.data().item.downloadURL)` nothings displays, I also tried `.refFromURL(item.downloadURL)`. and if I console log  `snapshot.data().downloadURL.url` nothing displays.

Comment: Can you tell me what `items` is. Do you have a screenshot of it as `json` maybe on the database. If you get the `downloadURL` with `item.downloadURL` I would recommend to use that directly and not from `snapshot`. I will update the answer

Comment: Now it works, thanks for the help. I updated my question with a working result. However, I changed firebase.storage to just storage() and then it works.

Comment: Ah sorry I changed that because I tought it was also a mistake. Great to hear it worked :)